# How many structs go into a file? in c

Tags: c, struct, mapping, mmap

I need to open a file that contains information and map that data using mmap. The data will be accessed by casting the mmap call with a struct. The problem is the file has information to fill approximately 3 structs because the data is repeated. So I need to access that information in chunks, I don't know if the explanation makes any sense.
The file has 384 bytes and the struct covers 128 bytes so I will need something like 3 structs in total.
I don't know how to do that. I already have mapped the file and printed the first struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct mapped
{
    /* Struct fields */
};


int main (int argc, char **argv){

    int fd = open("file",O_RDONLY,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);


    struct stat st;
    if(fstat(fd,&st)==-1) perror("Error\n");

    struct mapped *data = mmap(0,st.st_size,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE,fd,0);
   
    printf("\n");
    printf("File size: %li",st.st_size);
    printf("\n");
    printf(": %li",st.st_size);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    // print the struct data;
    printf("\n");

    
    close(fd);
    munmap(data,st.st_size);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: 3x128 is more than 348 -- you can't have 3 of the struct in that file.

Comment: `data++` will move the pointer forward. But it's better to use a separate `struct mapped *` so you can nicely `munmap`.

Comment: You need to map the whole file, not just the first 128 bytes. Then you can treat `data` as an array of `struct mapped`.

Comment: @Barmar well spotted, i missed that he used a hard coded 128 there. That should indeed be `st.st_size`.

Comment: Is 348 a typo and should be 384?

Comment: What is the question, here? Can you edit and clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didnt know I can treat  `data` as an array of structs